# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser doesn't run Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, browser

There is a link on a website I'm trying to click programmatically.  It worked for a while, then all of a sudden stopped.  I know, love these problems, right?

I figured the website changed a bit and I was just grabbing the wrong element now but that isn't the case.

When I try to manually click the link nothing happens - that's the odd part to me.  It works in IE, Mozilla, Chrome, etc...  Seems like javascript just stopped working with the webbrowser object.

The href is:
*href="javascript:SomeMethod('Param1', 'Param2', 'Param3')*

Is there a way to tell that all the javascript loaded properly?
Is there any setting I have to set to get javascript to work?

Note:  I have set WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true because in the past there were error on the page.

Thanks!

PS - I apologise they won't let me create a webbrowser or system.windows.forms.webbrowser tag...  Don't have the rep...

Update Aug 6:  I've done some reading and some asking around to determine what does IE do to this control that I do not?  Apparently there is some way to link my web browser control to the windows profile running it, using those internet permissions instead of the default ones, which could be the reason why nothing is running.  I haven't found how to do this yet.

Comment: The tag shouldn't be created because it's not supposed to be created, but you can use `winforms`  and `browser` tags.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
object[] o = new object[3];
            param1[0]=txtMessage.Text;
            param1[1]=txtMessage.Text;
            param1[2]=txtMessage.Text;
object result = this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SomeMethod('Param1', 'Param2', 'Param3')", o);
```

Comment: But why doesn't manually clicking the link activate the javascript?  Is this not a deeper problem with the browser?